# Why LazyVerticalGrid is not showing two columns with first all containing all images and second with all the names in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-cardview, kotlin-flow

I am trying to display a list of images and the it's names , where the first all column should contain all the images from the list and second column should contain all the names. But , it's only showing names in both the columns like this [image: It's looking like this]

I want all these names to be in second column and the images in first column. Below is the code for my Composable **PlayScreen**

// Play Screen to practice the learnt words

```
@Composable
fun PlayScreen() {
    // Create a ViewModel to handle the logic and data for the Composable
    val viewModel: PractiseViewModel = viewModel()
    val imageInfoList = viewModel.imageInfoList.value

    LazyVerticalGrid(cells = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
        items(imageInfoList.size) { index ->
            ImageInfoCard(imageInfoData = imageInfoList[index])
            Text(
                text = imageInfoList[index].name,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp),
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            )
        }
    }
}

fun generateImageList(): List<ImageInfoData> {
    val images = listOf(
        R.drawable.apple,
        R.drawable.mango,
        R.drawable.banana,
        R.drawable.coconut,
        R.drawable.orange
    )

    val imageNames = listOf("Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Coconut", "Orange")
    val shuffledNames = imageNames.shuffled()

    return images.zip(shuffledNames) { image, name ->
        ImageInfoData(image, name)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ImageInfoCard(imageInfoData: ImageInfoData) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp),
        onClick = {
            // Handle click event here
        }
    ) {
        Column {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = imageInfoData.imageResId),
                contentDescription = imageInfoData.name,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Green)
                    .width(180.dp)
                    .height(100.dp),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Inside
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PlayScreenPreview() {
    PlayScreen()
}
```

Below is the viewmodel that is used in PlayScreen **PractiseViewModel**

```
class PractiseViewModel:ViewModel() {

    //MutableStateFlow to hold the list of ImageInfoData

    private val _imageInfoList = MutableStateFlow<List<ImageInfoData>>(emptyList())
    val imageInfoList:StateFlow<List<ImageInfoData>> get() = _imageInfoList

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _imageInfoList.value = generateImageList()
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the data class that is used **ImageInfoData**

```
data class ImageInfoData(val imageResId:Int, val name:String)
```

I have tried using LazyverticalGrid and LazyColumns inside a LazyColumn but I am getting the same issue.

Comment: can you please give picture of what you want

Answer (score 1):

I have copiled your code and get this result by changing the height of the text which you have given `100.dp` was occupying all the heights of the item.

***You can find the complete example from the GITs.***

https://gist.github.com/chiragthummar/31689d97dbb5579199a1e556d21a40d9

**Code Output**
[image: code]

Comment: I eventually found a way to do in a diffrent way but I think if I have get an output on clicking a specific card, your way is helpful.

Comment: i did like this  https://github.com/klaus19/ComposeGrid/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the items, like

```
if (index % 2 == 0) {
  ImageInfoCard(...)
} else {
  Text(...)
}
```

Comment: can you give the code for eentire composable with updated code?